# bind label to model length in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to bind a label to length of model defined in component.js. I can get the length in component, but when I try to map the same inside view it returns **undefined**. I have binded table to that model and am able to get data inside table.

Here is my code in component.js

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/data.json");
var datacount ;
oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
     // console.log(this.getData().length);
     datacount = this.getData().length; //I am able to get length here
    oModel.setData({
        struct : this.getData(),
        number: datacount
    });
});
this.setModel(oModel, "MyJsonData");
```

Inside view:

```
oTable.bindRows("MyJsonData>/struct/");
var lbl = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "{MyJsonData>/number}"});
```

The label is not returning anything?

Comment: returns syntax error: "Expected ',' instead of '‌'"

Comment: Updated above code to var lbl = new sap.ui.commons.Label({
 text: "{path:'MyJsonData>/number'}",
 type:'sap.ui.model.type.Integer'});  No error but still label does not work

Comment: try using setProperty instead of setData on the model (you'll need 2 calls, one for struct, one for number)

Comment: Two calls is a not a good solution I guess, One call should work. I am okay to wait till it loads.

Answer (score 0):

Your model `MyJsonData` is not yet available when you are declaring the `Label`.

---

I tried with a similar example and observed this control flow:

Component `init()` -> view Controller -> `setModel()` statement -> `requestCompleted` handler

So if I plot a timeline this is what I'd see:

1. Your `Label` gets instantiated when there is no model available with `Component`.
2. Your model gets created without the `number` property.
3. You add a `number` property to the existing model `MyJsonData`.

**The solution:**

Do everything in your view's controller and inside the `requestCompleted` handler.

The `requestCompleted` event works asynchronously i.e. it allows further execution while waiting for data to load. So any statements outside the handler method would get executed *before* the handler does its magic.

**Note:**

- You can use `controller.getOwnerComponent()` to retrieve an instance of your `Component` and set your model on it.
- Your event handler wouldn't know what `oModel` is. You have to call `setData` on `this`.
- If you are trying to retrieve the text of the `Label` without first adding it to the UI DOM then make sure you explicitly bind your model to it.

In other words:

```
var lbl = new sap.ui.commons.Label({
    text: "{MyJsonData>/number}"
});
console.log(lbl.getText());
```

won't work because you haven't yet added `lbl` to the view and so it doesn't have access to the models. However, it would certainly print the text in your browser console if you did:

```
var lbl = new sap.ui.commons.Label({
    text: "{MyJsonData>/number}"
}).setModel(oModel, "MyJsonData");
```

Lastly, nobody uses `sap.ui.commons` anymore. I advise you to switch to `sap.m`.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explaination. the issue is I am on 1.28 and controller.getOwnerComponent() is still not supported. Secondly If I declare the model in init controller everything works fine but that is not the recommended usage. I want to use model defined in component.

Comment: For "your model MyJsonData is not yet available when you are declaring the Label". I am okay to wait - once the model is loaded then the label should update - similar to the case of table control. Right?

Comment: @Justin, apologies for replying so late. In the SDK documentation I see that `getOwnerComponent()` is available since _v1.23_. And yes once your model is available the `Label` should update, doesn't it?